# Paraphrase this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

I don't understand what the following sentence means. Would you please paraphrase it:

> You are more inclined to feel down to earth than somewhat removed.

**[Source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:x5XW3plcY5kJ:www.davidfroud.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Myers-Briggs-Test.xls%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ir)**

Comment: Could you be more specific which words are problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "You will probably feel calm, instead of absent minded."

"down to earth" generally means you are practical. It is the opposite of the idiom "head in the clouds".

> James always has his **head in the clouds**, he's never paying attention to what's happening around him.

Someone who has their head in the clouds is someone who is absent minded, or is paying less attention to what is happening around them than someone who is "down to earth".

"Somewhat removed" is speaking of the persons mental state, again. It is less than "head in the clouds" but still not quite "down to earth".